# (Discord.js) How do I create a new text channel inside of a category?

Tags: discord.js

Is there a way to format the `guild.channels.create()` method to create the channel inside of a category? The category is already created, I just need to create a channel under it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create) state that you can use the parent option to specify a parent:

```js
guild.channel.create('new-channel', {parent : id});
```

`id` should be the ID of the category.